# Regex to find = signs not surrounded by spaces and replace with spaces

Tags: regex, xcode

I've inherited code where no attention has been made with respect to white spacing and I'm in the process of fixing it.

My conditions that I'm looking for are to find an equal sign that is not surrounded by white space so I can replace them with " = ".

Once I do this, I'll be doing the same with "!=", ">", "==" and so on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can match this regex:

```
/\S([<>!=]=|[<>=])\S/
```

`\S` will match any non-white space on either side of these operators.

---

You can use this regex for matching:

```
\s*(?:(?<!\s)([<>!=]=|[<>=])|([<>!=]=|[<>=])(?!\s))\s*
```

And use this for replacement:

```
" $1 "
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll handle the == cases and the != cases first, then work my way back to handling the single = signs.

Comment: Yes `[<>!=]=` will match `<=, >=, !=, ==`

Comment: Hmmmm.  This fails in the case of "a ==b" and "a== b".  Can you be so kind as to explain the pattern of your regex?  Thanks much.

Comment: In which language/tool are you doing this?

Comment: Xcode's Find and Replace for iOS code.  Using Xcode 6.2.  Trying to put white space around all the cases where we have none in the conditions I described.

Comment: I've verified that in simple cases, yes.  These regexes for simply checking to see if a non space character precedes or follows the = do function as expected     **=(?! )**   and   **(?<! )=**

Comment: Awesome!  I can take it from here, friend!  Thanks much for your time.

Comment: A little followup: \S([<>!=]=|[<>=])\S works great.  I had to remove the leading and trailing / es and it really helps out in Xcode where people seem to think that white space doesn't matter around =, ==, !=, and so on.